# Question about the properties of AVL trees

Tags: data-structures, rank, avl-tree

> Assume that the oil company saves for each person that works in the
> company a record with its name, its salary, its age and its date of
> birth. You can assume that no two fields are identical for any two
> employees. a. The accounting department wants to store the records of
> all employees such that the following operations can be performed:
>
> **a./b./c./d. < not relevent >**
>
> **e.** Compute the average salary of the 10% of employees that earn the highest salaries.
>
> Suggest an efficient data structure that allows an efficient (worst
> time complexity and space complexity) for each of the above
> operations.

I was given the above problem, and opted to use an AVL tree with a few additional fields for each node, such as

i. Key = Salary

ii. Size = The number of nodes in left+right subtrees + 1

iii. Sum = The sum of salaries of all decendants + the salary of the node

My solution was to keep going to the right child until we reach a node that has node.Size = n/10. Each decendant of this node, let's call it k will have an higher salary than the parent of k, by the AVL tree properties. Hence, we have a subtree with n/10 nodes with the highest salaries in the AVL tree and all we have to do is return Sum/Size.
But the official solution (which also used an AVL with the fields I suggested) used the AVL tree properties to calculate the rank of the node as following

> To compute the average salary of the 10% of employees that earn the
> highest salaries. We first find the node v that has a rank
> 9n/10 , then we sum all keys that are larger than key(v),
> using the sum field in a set of nodes and divide the sum by
> n/10 . To find v we use the rank select recursive algorithm:
> The rank of the root is given by r=(size(left(root)). If
> r=9n/10 we are done. Otherwise, recursively searching in the
> left or the right subtree according to whether r<9n/10 (search  > in the left subtree) or r>9n/10 search in the right subtree for > an element with rank 9n/10 − .
> Then we sum the values of all keys that are larger than v using key(x)+
> sum(right(x)) field where x is a node on the path from v to the root
> (including v) and v is in the left subtree of x.

Their solution seems messy and I don't quiet understand it, but the idea to use the AVL tree properties to find the rank of a node sounds very useful and I would like to ask the following questions:

i. Does my solution produce the desired result?

ii. Can anyone explain a little bit better the procedure to find the rank of a given element of an AVL (and the additional augmented fields that will be required to do so)?

Comment: You're assuming that you will find a node with size exactly n/10 on the rightmost branch.  In most cases there won't be one.

Comment: I see, you're right. :)